# customized legends by data points in r dygraphs

Tags: r, legend, dygraphs

I understand using `dySeries` function from the R `dygraphs` package can customize the overall legend text. However, I wonder how to create customized legend text in dygraphs (or other tricks to reach the goal). As an example:

```
library(dygraphs)
data <- data.frame(game = c(1:5),
                   oppnt = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"),
                   score = c(10, 20, 15, 12, 4))

data %>% select(game, score) %>% dygraph() %>%
  dySeries("score", label = "X's score")
```

This will show X's score: (interactive score) when mouseover each data point. How can I show information like Opponent XXX, X's score: (interactive score). For example: "Opponent ccc, X's score: 15"? Thanks.